# Free memory allocated by LLVM

Tags: memory-management, llvm

I am struggling a little bit with finding how to free memory allocated by LLVM functions. For example, when I call the function `Function::Create()` to create an LLVM function, how can I free the memory allocated to it? Same actually applies to many LLVM functions like `IRBuilder::CreateAlloca()`, `IRBuilder::CreateStore()`, etc. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, when deleting *any* kind of [`Value`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Value.html), make sure it doesn't have any [`User`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1User.html)s anymore. Deleting used values will, obviously, lead to errors (in the form of an assertion). This can easily be tested by calling [`getNumUses()`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Value.html#a380559e99b47632a34f74de7c1d03cc0), or better (read: faster)  [`hasNUses(0)`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Value.html#ad58ff1cf33943e54cc5bed1aba593928).

When you're sure your value isn't used anymore, different kind of values sometimes need different ways to delete them. For your two cases:

- [`Function`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Function.html)s can simply be deleted by calling [`operator delete`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Function.html#a3b03f7cf0b75d16edebdda1dee1db6fd). This makes sure the function is removed correctly from the [`Module`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Module.html).
- [`Instruction`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html)s should be deleted by calling [`eraseFromParent()`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html#a6fe2f06b8a4b2c3d6308afb223a0238a). Or, equivalently, by first calling [`removeFromParent()`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html#a0fd53f63d349dc8a7c5fc0cdd7a94c8d) and then deleting it manually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But where do you find this information? LLVM's documentation doesn't seem to be that informative.

Comment: @Rafid: Yes, that's true. I basically know this by using LLVM a lot and reading the sources:-)

Comment: @Rafid: Also, a lot of useful information can be found in LLVM's [programmers manual](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html).

Comment: Thanks very much for the useful information! I will mark your answer as accepted, but I will get back to you whenever I need help :P

Comment: @Rafid if this wasn't clear, you should probably send a patch for the documentation